# How to pass and mock var args of object in method

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

This is the method of the class, for which , i want to write Unit Test case with mockito

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    // private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);
    public void insertData(Employee emp) {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO Emp"
                + "(first_name,last_name, gender, city) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)";

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        jdbcTemplate.update(
                sql,
                new Object[] { emp.getFirstName(), emp.getLastName(),
                        emp.getGender(), emp.getCity() });

    }
|
```

Below i have written my testcase method:

```
@Test
public void insertDataTest() {

    Employee emp= new Employee();
    emp.setUserId(1);
    emp.setFirstName("Somya");
    emp.setLastName("Kumari");
    emp.setGender("female");
    emp.setCity("Bangalore");
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    int var = 0;

    Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.update(Mockito.anyString(),
           Mockito.anyVararg())).thenReturn(var);

    empDao.insertData(emp);

    withSuccess();

}
```

This is the error i am getting , please help me.

[image: Error Console]

Comment: I can't quite predict the cause of the error, yet, as Mockito can be kind of cryptic, but I don't think this is going to work for you.  `jdbcTemplate` in your test case isn't a mock object, so I think you'll get some exception eventually about not being able to return mocked values from non-mocks.

Comment: Further the `JdbcTemplate` in the test isn't the same one that's in the code.  You can mock it all you want, but it won't change the behavior of the code under test, which is creating a brand new `JdbcTemplate`.  You might want to use some dependency injection to manipulate the object actually used in the code under test.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to be tested?  That `jdbcTemplate.update` is called when you pass an `Employee` to `insertData`?

Comment: I'm also unfamiliar with `withSuccess`.  It looks like it might come from Spring, but even then that's not its normal usage.

Comment: JdbcTemplate is thread safe so instead of auto wiring the data source, auto wire a JdbcTemplate.  This avoids the code from having to create a new JdbcTemplate instance, and also simplifies the test by injecting a mock JdbcTemplate.  Then simply verify the mock JdbcTemplate was invoked with the expected parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `@Mock` of jdbcTemplate in your testclass:

```
@Mock private JdbcTemplate template;
```

Since you are not getting any `NPE`  but `InvalidUseOfMatchersException:`, This simply means that you have an instance injected in your test class either using @Autowired or maybe new operator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the arguments in your `when` call.  Otherwise the arguments will be ambiguous and the compiler is unable to resolve it to a specific `update` method.

So:

```
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.update((String)Mockito.anyString(), (Object[])Mockito.anyVararg())).thenReturn(var);
```

should resolve your issue.  At least it did for me.